# How to update cordova (phonegap) plugin in my project?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Anyone knows what is the proper way to update cordova plugin in my cordova/phonegap project? Some time ago I installed file plugin as:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

Everything worked fine. Now I realized there is a new version of the file plugin, so I wanted to update to get the new functionality. However, I haven't found a decent way to update. Actually, I can't update at all.

When I run remove command as:

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file
```

I get the following message:

```
Deleting plugin org.apache.cordova.file
No dangling plugins to remove.
```

What is interesting is that if I run

```
cordova plugin
```

right after, I still see org.apache.cordova.file in the list of installed plugins. Also, there is no single change on a file system. Nothing is removed, no file is updated.

Then I try to add a plugin again (as for updating the plugin is advised to remove it and add again) with:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

Which outputs:

```
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.file" via plugin registry
Plugin "org.apache.cordova.file" already installed on android.
Plugin "org.apache.cordova.file" already installed on ios.
```

And, even though this brings new version of java and javascript files (and some others), as I would expect, it brings them to myproject/plugins folder only.

It doesn't update files in platform folders (myproject/platforms/android/assets/www/plugins and myproject/platforms/ios/www/plugins) where it installed the files I installed them the first time.

Thus my project still keeps using the old version of the plugin.

So I wonder, how to update plugins. Any idea? Do I have to copy them manually to platform folders? Is this documented anywhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So eventually I found the issue.

It seems, that there is a some sort of dependency between `org.apache.cordova.file` and `org.apache.cordova.file-transfer`. So if `file-transfer` plugin is installed, file plugin will not be removed, hence not updated if platform folders.

The solution is to remove `file-transfer` plugin first and then remove file plugin. Then adding file and `file-transfer` plugins will update those plugins in all platforms correctly, as one would expect.

Took some time to figure out, but does the trick.

Comment: There's a similar dependency with the org.apache.cordova.media plugin that also prevents removal of the org.apache.cordova.file plugin. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party, but I've added an option to my [cordova-check-plugins](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-check-plugins) tool that may be useful in this case:

> [`--force-update`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-check-plugins#--force-update)
>
> Forces the update of dependent plugins. By default, Cordova/Phonegap
>   will not allow the removal of plugins on which other plugins are
>   dependent, and therefore will not allow them to be updated. For
>   example, `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` depends on
>   `cordova-plugin-file`. By setting this option, both plugins will be
>   updated (if updates are available). Without it, only the "parent"
>   plugin - in this case `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` - will be
>   updated.

So if you install the tool globally:

```
$ npm install -g cordova-check-plugins
```

Then run from the root of your Cordova project, you can force the update of plugins which Cordova will not allow to be removed (e.g. `cordova-plugin-file`) due to other plugins being dependent on them (e.g. `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`):

```
$ cordova-check-plugins --update=auto --force-update
```